# Creating a custom user registration for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have been requested to build a wordpress site but the user registration process needs to be customized, ie: I need to add in fields that are not currently used in the current wp system. I need to add in a Region field for example..

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [add_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

Answer (score 0):

Also there's the Profile Builder plugin: http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/

You can add all sort of extra fields and also display them on the front end.